# while loop how to echo distinct only one value and rest according to echo one

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
echo "id event </br>".$b[id_event] ."</br>";
echo "id user </br>".$b[id_user] ."</br>";
```

it's output

```
3 - 32
3 - 36
4 - 32
4 - 36
```

I want make it to display all users under one event id, like that

```
3 - 32, 36
4 - 32, 36
```

I tried like that

`while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {if ($b['id_event'] != $current_event) {
  $current_event = $b['id_event'];
echo '<br>' . $b['id_event'] . ' - ' . $b['id_user'];
  } else { echo ', ';}}`

but it selected only one user for one event id

```
 3 - 32, 
4 - 32,
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the results to an intermediate list for processing.

Check out the PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/evx-g61

```
$event_list = array();

while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($b["id_event"], $event_list)) {
        $event_list[$b["id_event"]] = array();
    }
    $event_list[$b["id_event"]][] = $b["id_user"];
}

foreach ($event_list as $event => $users) {
    echo "<span>$event - " . join(", ", $users) . "</span><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It work's fine but I can't display data for each $users   when I'm using join commend

```
foreach ($event_list as $event => $users) {
echo "<span>$event - " . join( $users,"some data") . "</span><br />";}
```

it's echo

```
3 - 36a32 
4 - 36a32
```

and I was expecting

```
3 - 36a32a
4 - 36a32a
```